# How get Month number instead of name in type="month" in @html helper

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages

I have to display month number instead of it's name
i am using type='month' in html.helper

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueMonth, new
                        {
                            htmlAttributes = new
                            {
                                @class = "form-control",
                                type = "month",
                                @Value = Model.DueMonth!= null ? 
                                 Model.DueMonth.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM") : null
                            }
                        })
```

**
but it is displaying
March 2023
i have to display 03 2023**

Comment: `Model.DueMonth.ToString("MM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will give you 03 2023

Comment: What type is `Date`?

Comment: FYI, you can simply your code using the null-conditional operator: `@Value = Model.DueMonth?.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "yyyy-MM" use "MM yyyy".

Like this

```
@Value = Model.DueMonth != null ? Model.DueMonth.Date.ToString("MM yyyy") : null
```

Comment: Hi have tried this, this show's noting

Answer (score 1):

The UI provided by the `input type="date"` is controlled by the browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month). If you want to control the format, you can do one of three things:

1. Change the input type to `text`
2. Write some JavaScript/CSS to mask the display part of the control with your own version
3. Find a third party component that provides what you need.